# How to register an ActiveX control?

Tags: c++, registry, activex, ocx

If I don't even know its name...
I dowloaded VC++ project and it crashes because of the dialog's ActiveX control.

The error is:

"The ActiveX control "09551E46-E250-11D2-9A56-0080C605ADA4" is not registered on this computer. Register the control and try again."

Which .ocx file do I need?

Comment: We do expect you to do a *little* research - like sticking that GUID into Google first.  (Admittedly, when I do it, this question is the top hit, but there's the link that roalz posts below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a quick search on the web, that GUID may identify the [MMWaveEditX - Advanced Wave File Editor Control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1319/MMWaveEditX-Advanced-Wave-File-Editor-Control)

Comment: @Nika_Rika Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work